# Magento 2 Commerce Edition - Category Image upload error : Attention File validation failed

Tags: category, image-upload, magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

I am getting the following error when i try to add image for category,

[image]

How to solve this issue, i am using commerce edition ver 2.4.1

Comment: hi there, can you check that you have the PHP fileinfo module installed?

Comment: Thank you, issue solved.

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: After remove ; from fileinfo in php.ini, that's it. thank you.

Comment: Can i get help for this https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330485/57334

Comment: ok, then I will mark the fileinfo mention as an answer to your question so that's more visible, maybe it will help  others in the future. please mark it as a solution afterwards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119289/discussion-between-zus-and-diana-botean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems to be a problem with the PHP fileinfo module. just make sure this is installed and enabled on your environment.